# How to auto-fill the linkedin advanced search current company using script in console?

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api

I want to auto-fill the `linkedin advanced search` form using the script in console. Particularly `current company` field

#### Steps to reach advanced search:

1. Login to `linkedin`
2. Click on `Advanced` option(Right to search)
3. You have see `Advance People Search` Option, Current Company is third field in that form

`Note:` How to auto-fill this particular field(current company).

Any suggestion will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to find out the ID's of the fields you want to fill.

Lets for example take the registration form on the linkedin website.

In Firefox a simple right click on the desired input followed by the key `Q` will get you to the Inspektor and highlight the clicked input. Here you can see the ID of the element.

In my case it was the input `first name`. The ID of this element is `firstName-coldRegistrationForm`.

With this information you can simply type the following in your console and `My Text` should be the new value in the input.

`document.getElementById('firstName-coldRegistrationForm').value = "My Text"`

Comment: Thanks for the info, But advanced search is different and particular curent company is very hard to fill, Could you please help me out.

Comment: Edited the question please look into it